# Python and zlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, zlib

That is basic, but what is the difference between

```
codecs.encode(bytes(str, 'utf-8'),encoding='zlib_codec',errors='strict')
```

and

```
zlib.compress(bytes(str, 'utf-8'), 2)
```

plain encoding and compressing?

What is the point of the first then?